# WS_EX_COMPOSITED cause unexpected WM_PAINT

Tags: c, windows, winapi, user-interface

Create a window with WS_EX_COMPOSITED style:

```
   hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_COMPOSITED, szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

Set caret for the window:

```
case WM_PAINT:
    OutputDebugStringA("WM_PAINT");
    hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    // TODO: Add any drawing code here...
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    break;
case WM_SETFOCUS:
    ::DestroyCaret();
    ::CreateCaret(hWnd, NULL, 2, 12);
    ::SetCaretPos(200, 200);
    ::ShowCaret(hWnd);
    break;
case WM_KILLFOCUS:
    ::DestroyCaret();
    break;
case WM_CHAR:
    ::DestroyCaret();
    ::CreateCaret(hWnd, NULL, 2, 12);
    ::SetCaretPos(200, 200);
    ::ShowCaret(hWnd);
    break;
```

Start the application, and do nothing. they will be a infinite WM_PAINT until hide the caret or destory the caret.

Spy++ shows:
every 0x118(WM_SYSTIMER) which blink the caret is followed by a WM_PAINT message.

The paint structure returned by BeginPaint is

`WM_PAINT : invaliate rect width = 2, height = 12`

which is just the width and height of the caret. In conclusion, WM_PAINT is for blinking the caret.

But if I remove the WM_EX_COMPOSITED style from the extra styles for the window, there is no infinite WM_PAINT anymore.

Is this a bug of windows?

PS: test enviroment windows 7 64bit + visual studio 2012.

Comment: Is your WndProc returning 0 to indicate that it handled WM_PAINT?

Comment: @selbie: Yes, my project is derived from the visual studio 2012 win32 application template, which definitly return 0. Actually, I only add the above lines.

Comment: WS_EX_COMPOSITED has a *big* effect on the way a window is rendered.  The top-level window and all its child controls are double-buffered.  You would not want the entire window stack to be repainted to just update a caret.  So this is almost certainly by design.  It should not be a problem.

Comment: If you're just using composited to prevent flicker when resizing, one possible solution is to only turn on the style when you enter your size loop, and turn it off again afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

A caret is also considered a control. Do not use WS_EX_COMPOSITED for top level windows. Either use it for the specific problematic control.

Or ignore WM_ERASEBACKGROUND in WndProc of a control which has foreground content covering it's whole client area, and the control flickers when you resize.